# C# exception anywhere in the application

Tags: c#, .net, exception, unhandled-exception

i have a C# application that is crashing "stopped working" and i am not a C# guru. From what i saw on the internet, the main reason for a C# application crash is an unhandled exception (i don't know why you're not forced to use try catch in c# like in java). Is there a way to catch an unhandled exception that occurred anywhere in the application? Like in Main maybe? I don't really want to go through 50 classes and properly add try catch blocks.

Comment: You could theoretically put try-catch block in the very beginning of your application, for example...

Comment: Why wouldn't you add try-catch in the main function?

Comment: You should be able to look at the StackTrace from the error which will usually allow you to see where the error stemmed from (e.g. {method-name}:{line-number}). You may also be able to check the Event Viewer on your machine to attempt to find additional information there.

Comment: @user3114639 well, you could... but how/what are you expecting to do with an exception when you ***do*** catch one?  Just swallow it?  Yeah that could prevent your program from crashing, but some other nasty stuff might happen, some of which could be much worse than the application crashing depending on the current state.

Comment: @ian he said there are over 50 classes. I dont think that would work.

Comment: Quote 1: "(i don't know why you're not forced to use try catch in c# like in java)" but then Quote 2: "I don't really want to go through 50 classes and properly add try catch blocks". That's why checked exceptions suck. (and they are wrong by design imo)

Comment: @user3114639 i already have a try catch in my main but i think because the application is using threads, the exception of a different thread is not caught.

Comment: @RionWilliams yes, but i do not have a screenshot of the problem, only a log which does not display unhandled exceptions, and reproducing it would take a few days